# specific url on TinyMCE doesn't work, php

Tags: php, html, sql, url

I need to show a text that contains a url, this text is write in a tinyMCE component, but when I submit the information, like:

**" hi, this is a test page : http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action;jsessionid=532B991BB49D040D59980727CCB70131?pageId=236425205 "**

It is only recorded in My DB and debuging the code the part:

'

http //tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action;jsessi>'

I tried use various PHP functions to solve the problem, like htmlentities, filter_var , htmlspecialchars but i can't find the error,

When I removed the jsessionid on URL, works, but i don't know why, but i need the complete url, Advise? Thanks